# Determining convergence/divergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{n^2+7} -n $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Determining convergence/divergence of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{n^2+7} -n $$
I tried applying ratio test but I realised the denominator was $0$.

Any tips for what test to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Use that

$$\sqrt{n^2+7} -n=(\sqrt{n^2+7} -n)\cdot \frac{\sqrt{n^2+7} +n}{\sqrt{n^2+7} +n}$$

and then refer to limit comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

Using the difference of squares identity, we have

$$
\sqrt{n^2+7}-n={(n^2+7)-n^2\over\sqrt{n^2+7}+n}\sim{7\over2n}
$$

Since the Harmonic series diverges, we conclude that series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sqrt{n^2+7}-n^2\right)
$$

diverges too.

Answer (score 0):

Write:

$\sqrt{n^2+7}-n=\sqrt{n^2+7}-\sqrt{n^2}=\frac{(\sqrt{n^2+7}-\sqrt{n^2})(\sqrt{n^2+7}+\sqrt{n^2})}{\sqrt{n^2+7}+\sqrt{n^2}}=\frac{7}{\sqrt{n^2+7}+n}$

Now compare with the harmonic series.

Answer (score 0):

For all naturals,

$$n^2+7>n^2+2+\frac1{n^2}$$ so that $$\sqrt{n^2+7}-n>\frac1n.$$ You can conclude.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n=n(1+7/n^2)^{1/2}-n=$

$n(1+(1/2)7/n^2+O(1/n^4))-n=$

$(7/2)(1/n)+O(1/n^3);$

Comparison test.